# Is it possible to handle an arbitrarily large string in Python? (created via the * operator)

Tags: python, string

We can build strings of fixed structure but arbitrary length with the * operator, with the following:

```
length = 10
print "0" * length
```

This returns what is expected, `0000000000`.  The problem arises when length is excessively large, resulting in an overflow error:

```
length = 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
print "0" * length
```

This results in `OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer`.

I am curious, can such a formulation somehow be used for sizes of arbitrary length?  Or what is the correct way to handle a scenario where `length` is unknown and may take on such a large value?

Comment: You do realize that no existing system could handle the amount of data necessary for such a string? Your number is 10^46. That's way more data than Google has or will ever have.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Perhaps, but I don't think that makes it impossible, which is why I posed the question.  That is a valid concern to keep in mind, though.

Comment: I'm curious which problem domain deals with such large strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot create large strings like the one in your example in *any* programming language. Strings contain each character on its own. And 10<sup>46</sup> bytes is most likely way more data than anyone will ever store. You could take way over a trillion Google datacenters (assuming Google has 1 YiB of storage which is surely not the case yet..) and *still* have much less *disk* space, let alone RAM which would be what you'd need for such a string.

To store a huge string like the one from your example you'd have to create your own `str`-like class that handles `__mul__` in a way where the number of repetitions are stored without actually storing the whole string in memory. Obviously this implementation would become extremely complex as soon as you allow modifications to that string.

Comment: Interesting, I think that may be the simplest way: writing a wrapper around the string class that stores the original pattern (which is passed in quotes) and the multiplication factor.  It's clear that you cannot store the string in its obvious format, but the string's possible values are very constrained, making it tractable.  Very cool, thanks!  Interesting problem to think about.

Comment: Have fun supporting stuff like `foo = some_huge_str[:10**10] + some_huge_str[10**20:10**30]` :p

Answer (score 3):

You may write something like string generator in python. For example:

```
import sys

def stringWithArbitraryLength(stringLength):
    n = 0
    while n < stringLength:
        # pattern here
        if n % 2 == 0:
            yield "0"
        else:
            yield "1"
        n += 1

Infinity = float('inf')

# Usage 1: print the long string
# for c in stringWithArbitraryLength(Infinity):
#   sys.stdout.write(c)

# Usage 2: instantiate the long string
soLong = stringWithArbitraryLength(100000)  # output 01010101....
print ''.join(soLong)

# Usage 3: transform the long string
def transformString(longLongString):
    for c in longLongString:
        if c == "1":
            yield "X"
        else:
            yield c
soLong2 = stringWithArbitraryLength(100000)  # output 0X0X0X0X....
print ''.join(transformString(soLong2))
```

It has several limitations:

1. It allows only sequential access, not random access. So you have to use for-loop to walk through the string.
2. Each character cannot depend on characters with larger indices.
3. Instantiation is difficult if the length is large. But you can do random access after instantiation.

In many cases, you don't have to instantiate the whole string. Because you can use IO stream to do input/output. And use generator to process the string. So each time you handle part of the data only.

If you want to understand more about long, or infinitely long, string, you may learn some non-strict functional languages, for example, Haskell. It evaluates expression lazily. Infinity list/string are often used in these languages.